# PHP: Get key in multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an `Array` like this :

```
Array ( [48948171] => Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [name] => Kog'Maw's Deceivers [tier] => BRONZE [queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5 [entries] => Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [playerOrTeamId] => 46337778 [playerOrTeamName] => EmaOwnaBan [division] => IV [leaguePoints] => 57 [wins] => 19 [losses] => 15 [isHotStreak] => 1 [isVeteran] => [isFreshBlood] => [isInactive] => ) 

[1] => Array ( [playerOrTeamId] => 68938894 [playerOrTeamName] => KillerBrownieGRH [division] => V [leaguePoints] => 49 [wins] => 20 [losses] => 39 [isHotStreak] => [isVeteran] => [isFreshBlood] => [isInactive] => )
....
```

My question: How do I get the main-key just from having the `playerOrTeamId`, for example: I have `playerOrTeamId=68938894`, now I want to get `[1]` as result, so that I can get the `division` of a player with

```
$summoner_league[$summoner_id][0]["entries"][NUMBERINEEDTOKNOW]["division"]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think, you have to search...

Comment: did not find any similar to this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get **68938894** index as:

```
$reqArr = array();

foreach($yourArr as $value){
     foreach($value as $innerVal){
          if($innerVal["playerOrTeamId"] == 68938894){
               $reqArr = $innerVal;
          }
      }
}
print_r($reqArr);
```

Comment: i tried it and edited it like that: `$reqArr = array();

foreach($summoner_league as $value){
     foreach($value as $innerVal){
          if($innerVal["playerOrTeamId"] == 68938894){
               $reqArr = $innerVal;
          }
      }
}
print_r($reqArr);` gives me: Notice: Undefined index: playerOrTeamId

Comment: no error, just: Notice: Undefined index: playerOrTeamId in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 65

Comment: i do not really understand your code. Your code returns me an array, but i want to get the key, an integer.

Comment: @user2230083:   foreach($yourArr as $value){
     foreach($value as $innerVal){ foreach($innerVal as $innerVal2){
          if($innerVal2["playerOrTeamId"] == 68938894){
               $reqArr = $innerVal2;
          }
      }
}}

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 66

Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 66

Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: playerOrTeamId in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 66

Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 66

Comment: @user2230083 than my ist example is fine... Before if() condition chk what rcu getting `print_r($innerVal);`

Comment: `Array ( [name] => Kog'Maw's Deceivers [tier] => BRONZE [..` with 'print_r($innerVal);', `Kog'Maw's Deceivers
Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 67
BRONZE
Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 67
RANKED_SOLO_5x5
Warning: Illegal string offset 'playerOrTeamId' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Summoner's Index\summonersindex.php on line 67
Array ( [0] => Array ( [playerOrTeamId] => 46337778 ...` with print_r($innerVal2);

Comment: okay dude, i managed it this way, and it works: `foreach($summoner_league as $value){ 
  foreach($value as $innerVal){ 
    foreach($innerVal as $innerVal2){
      foreach($innerVal2 as $innerVal3){   
        //print_r($innerVal3);
      if($innerVal3['playerOrTeamId'] == $summoner_id){ 
        $reqArr = $innerVal3; } } }}       }
print_r($reqArr);` now i get the vaylues that i want, only problem is i get this notice as well: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 66`. line 66: `foreach($innerVal2 as $innerVal3){`. whats wrong?

Comment: @bastianum this is not an array `$innerVal2`

Comment: well still it works, what do i need to do to get rid of this warning message?

Comment: Chk if `is_array()` use foreach @bastianum

Comment: `if(is_array($summoner_league))
foreach($summoner_league as $value){ 
  if(is_array($value))
  echo 1;
  foreach($value as $innerVal){ 
    if(is_array($innerVal))
    echo 2;
    foreach($innerVal as $innerVal2){
      if(is_array($innerVal2))
      echo 3;
      foreach($innerVal2 as $innerVal3){   
      if($innerVal3['playerOrTeamId'] == $summoner_id){ 
        $summoner_league_specified = $innerVal3; } } }}` gives me: **12
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** (3times) **3
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: nevermind, got it working now.(`if(is_array($innerVal2))  
      foreach($innerVal2 as $innerVal3){...`) thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: @bastianum hahah I told u brother... Good eork

Answer (score 0):

you can loop you array by this way:

```
foreach($arr_main as $arr_internal) {
    foreach($arr_internal['entries'] as $arr_entries) {
        echo $arr_entries['division'];
    }
}
```

Comment: that doenst really help me, i don't know how to use this for my problem, but still thanks. :)